# Magento2: Item (Magento\Framework\DataObject) with the same ID "52713" already exists

Tags: magento2, product

Step: Edit product and click on save button then got the error message below:

Item (Magento\Framework\DataObject) with the same ID "52713" already exists.

When I search for the id item 52713, I don't find it ! Can you help me please ? Thank you

Magento ver. 2.0.17

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "duplicate an item"? What's the item? how are you duplicating it? code or UI?

Comment: @Marius I am trying to simle edit product and then click on save button from backend got the error message.

Comment: @Marius Error message: Item (Magento\Framework\DataObject) with the same ID "52713" already exists.

Comment: @Marius Please see the screenshot in the quetion